# Laravel converts aws host address to ip adress

Tags: mysql, laravel, xampp

Trying to connect laravel app to AWS RDS, my .env looks like following:

```
DB_HOST_activation=****.c9j30pidhj1o.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_PORT_activation=3306
DB_DATABASE_activation=***
DB_USERNAME_activation=***
DB_PASSWORD_activation=******
```

Database config file looks like this:

```
 'activation' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST_activation', '****.c9j30pidhj1o.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT_activation', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_activation', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_activation', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_activation', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

Still I am getting the following error:

[image]

Somehow the aws host address is getting converted into IP address.

Comment: Did you enable remote access? https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: Yes, I did. I can connect from mysql-work-bench easily.

Comment: The IP shown is the IP of your web server. Make sure that user can connect from that IP.